# Not able to get security token from salesforce server

Tags: salesforce

I am not able to get access token from salesforce instance, Can anyone help me out from this.
I have tried many different ways, but not able to actually get it done :(.

```
HttpClient httpclient2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://instance.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", CONSUMER_KEY));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", SECRET_KEY));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "emailaddress"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password+securityToken));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
HttpResponse response = httpclient2.execute(post);
String body = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println(body);
```

It is giving below error : 
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What, exactly, happens?

Comment: I have added in question

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is you need to use `login.salesforce.com` as the login host, not `<instance>.salesforce.com` but if that doesn't work, here is a complete example that uses `httpclient` to login and then make a query: https://github.com/jamesward/salesforce-rest-starter

Answer (score 0):

It has over 2 days but Finally, I have done it :).

Program was correct but there was missing something with Configuration from Salesforce side. Below is the missing configuration which fixed my issue.

[image]

Thanks.